indexerrors in list loops
So I'm trying to do a program where you enter a function, evaluate it in some points contained within a list and then make a list with the results.
The code I wrote is:
def S(N, E, A):
    samples = []
    for x in range(1,N,1):
        samples.append(A + E/x)
    for y in range(-N, -1, 1):
        samples.append(A - E/y)
    return samples

def f(x):
    return eval(str(input("function: ")))

def P(list, N):
    results = []
    k = range(2*N+1)
    for x in k:
       results.append(f(list[x]))
    return results

samp = S(n, e, a)
fRes = P(samp, n)

So the idea is to pick some points on a set bounded by e, evaluate the function on it, and collect the result in a list. Concretely, we pick 2n points, n to the left and n to the right, starting at some center a.
However, I don't know what I'm doing wrong because when I run the code, it outputs.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 41, in <module>      
    fRes = P(samp, n)
  File "", line 35, in P(list, N)       
    results.append(f(list[x]))
IndexError: list index out of range

I just don't know how to fix it. I've tried almost everything I know originally, instead of for loops I used while loops, but nothing could fix it, help.

See here?

python range exclude the end step. in your S function you only create 2*(N-1) samples

Very common error, have you referred to this?
Does "IndexError: list index out of range" when trying to access the N'th item mean that my list has less than N items?
In your specific instance, I suspect that the line k=range(2*N+1) is causing your error. Why the +1? If you’re writing for x in k, you’re already specifying the for loop to iterate over list for k number of times. If you add one to k, your for loop will count one extra time, where it will find that the length of your list is just 2N, not 2N+1, and since there isn’t a value at that extra +1 index of your list…  error!
Remove that +1. Or, use the much easier and foolproof way to find the length of your list without manually calculating k: Python’s len() function! for x in range(0, len(list))

Thank you for answering, i included that +1 there because list indices start from 0 so if i want it to go from 0 to 2N then i should include a +1. Thinking better about it it should include a -1 instead, sorry it was late night and i was tired

All good! Happens to all of us. Could you resolve the question by accepting an answer?
